# TYPO3 - tx_news - Show related articles on detail page except current article

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x, tx-news, typo3-8.7.x

On the detail page of a tx_news record I also provide 'related articles' of the current article/record ... with the below snippet. But in the suggested 'related articles' the current record is also provided. How can I exclude the current article from the suggested list?

Typoscript:

```
lib.relatedByFirstCategory.articles = USER
lib.relatedByFirstCategory.articles {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    extensionName = News
    pluginName = Pi1
    vendorName = GeorgRinger

    switchableControllerActions {
        News {
            1 = list
        }
    }

    settings < plugin.tx_news.settings
    settings {
        #relatedView = 1
        detailPid = 97
        useStdWrap := addToList(categories)
        categories.current = 1
        categoryConjunction = or
        overrideFlexformSettingsIfEmpty := addToList(detailPid)
        startingpoint = 96
        templateLayout = 4
        hidePagination = 1
        # added
        excludeAlreadyDisplayedNews =1        
    }
}
```

News Detail.html

```
<!-- related articles -->
    <f:if condition="{newsItem.firstCategory}">     
        <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.relatedByFirstCategory.articles">{newsItem.firstCategory.uid}</f:cObject>
    </f:if>                 
</f:if>
```

Source: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/stable/singlehtml/Index.html#show-news-items-with-same-category-in-detail-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`excludeAlreadyDisplayedNews` is your friend. Look here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/stable/singlehtml/Index.html#excludealreadydisplayednews